# Strange behavior sending data through Ajax to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I'm building a website using my own php base of code used in a previous website but after 2 months, I'm using the same base and something is happening receiving the data in the PHP file to process the information using jQuery ajax and I really don't understand the error:

When I send data, in the Form Data option in Google Chrome developers tools is showing only the fields texts with their data but when I print this POST data using var_dump(), all this text is printed:

[image]
[image]

About the Javascript code, is a simple ajax code like this:

```
var doFunction = function($form)
{

var form_data =  $form.serialize();

var data = {
    form: form_data,
    tag: 'save'
};

$.ajax({
    url: 'routes.php',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: data
})
.done(function(data) {

})
.fail(function(jqXHR) {

})
.always(function() {

});

return false;
}
```

And the PHP code is only a var_dump($_POST); only to check the data. A simple explanation about the error is like if I'm sending this data:

```
Name: 'My Name',
Tag: 'save'
```

PHP code is showing

```
My name: 'Name',
save: 'Tag'
```

Or something like that.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: can you try changing your data to just the serialised form ? `var data =  $form.serialize();` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried that and even with serializeArray(); but is the same result.

Comment: Your code appears fine, and the php side is outputting the variables as expected.  The first line of the PHP response confirms this - the variables are output as an array.  However, you say that the server side code is `var_dump($_POST);` only.  However, this does not explain all the additional php errors - which would only exist if there was further code.  Check that your server side code is correct.

Comment: you should be showing us the form and the corresponding php file, I could see that the form data doesn't have the required fields.

Answer (score 0):

You're sending the data to PHP incorrectly.  This is the part you are messing up:

```
var data = {
    form: form_data,
    tag: 'save'
};
```

Instead of doing that do this and it will work:

```
var data = form_data + "&tag=save"
```

Basically what is happening is you're mixing up 2 different formats.  The serialize function returns a string with key value pairs separated by an ampersand (&).  However when you're adding tag:"save", you are using a javascript object.

Since you mixed them both up you are only sending 2 post variables up to your php script.  $_POST['form'] which is a string with key value pairs separated by an ampersand (&) and $_POST['tag'] which is set to "save".

Your PHP script looks like it's expecting "nombre" as a POST variable which won't exist, and throw a notice.

Comment: The structure to sending data is ok, the problem was that is not working with Chrome but with another browsers works perfectly I'm still don't know why but now it's working.